# Reloading or refreshing page removes authorization in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application

I'm using social authentication using the [vue-google-oauth2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-oauth2) library. It works fine as I am able to authenticate my self and I receive a token from the backend too.

When initially I log in, and by using a function that is part of the vue-google-oauth2 library that I'm using to check if it says that I'm authorized or not, it gives the following response in my browser's console:

> this.$gAuth.isAuthorized
>
> true

When I then refresh my browser page, and since I've placed a debugger command in my code, and I print the same function again,
I get the following response:

> this.$gAuth.isAuthorized
>
> false

What can I do to ensure that switching tabs, reloading page or refreshing it won't make this happen? Or is this what is actually supposed to be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at saving it in as session data? Im not to familiar how Angular state works, but when you set original state you can look for the session key "authorized" and if it doesnt exist set auth to false, if it exists set it to the value.

`localstorage.getItem(item)`
and 
`localstorage.setItem(item)`

There is also the option of making a component that handles the google auth and sends it to the state.

Answer (score 0):

From the library documentation for `vue-google-oauth` page you linked it says you need to send that code back to your backend server to create a token to stay signed in, so it's behaving as expected.  From here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-oauth2#usage---getting-authorization-code) it states :

> The authCode that is being returned is the one-time code that you can
>   send to your backend server, so that the server can exchange for its
>   own access_token and refresh_token

In other words, you need to do something with that code to make it persist in your app, otherwise it's just a one-time code, so looks to be expected.

Comment: So does that mean that the functions that are mentioned in the library are only to be used when the login/registration process is being carried out. Will I have to somehow create my own session and maintain it too?

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to do something like that.  There's a flow chart at the bottom of that documentation page that lays it out better than I can.